# Copy database when phone hasn't got external memory

Tags: android, backup

I have got a problem with backup database in my app. I am working on Android 2.2.3 and this has sd card installed. Making copy of the database works fine. The problem occures when I'am testing my app on the phone with internal memory enought big like sd cards (Nexus 32gb). In this scenario my method doesn't work extracting file to sd card because it doesn't (sd card) exist. How to make copy of database to internal independed location? I've tried:

```
File outPut = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().toString() + "/myfolder/");
```

but got permission denied and can not create folder with data. Can anyone show correct way?

EDITED:

I don't get it. I'd like to make new folder with dataBackup. I've defined correct location for that but it says that can not find file. SDCard is present. Why it can not create that folder - "/storeUGif/databaseName.db".?

Here is absolute path for destination folder:

```
public static final String OUTPUT_BACKUP_DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storeUGif/" + SqliteHelper.DATABASE_NAME;


if(isSdPresent())
        {
            //File outPut = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/StoreUGif/"+SqliteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);

            File outPut = new File(Tools.OUTPUT_BACKUP_DATABASE);

            File storeUGif = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString());
            storeUGif.mkdir();
            File currentDB = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(SqliteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(currentDB);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outPut);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


            while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {


                os.write(buffer);


            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SDCard is unvailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: try: File outPut = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"myfolder");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get a valid path.
Despite its name, it will return the default storage, either the external or (if missiing) the internal one.

For reference: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've got another problem again and I don't understand why it is stoped....;/ I have edited post